Issue with CORS Policy for Google Cloud Storage Video Files in ArcGIS Enterprise
I'm facing a CORS policy issue when trying to access video files stored in Google Cloud Storage from an application in ArcGIS Enterprise. The specific error message I receive is:

Access to image at 'https://storage.googleapis.com/pomerleauoic/DJI_20240612163254_0001.MP4' from origin 'https://gis.pomerleau.ca' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

Here are the steps I've taken to resolve the issue:

Updated the CORS configuration for my Google Cloud Storage bucket with the following settings:
"origin": ["https://gis.pomerleau.ca"],
"method": ["GET"],
"responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-
Credentials"],
"maxAgeSeconds": 3600

I verified that the CORS configuration is correctly applied using gsutil cors get gs://pomerleauoic.

Cleared browser cache and tested in different browsers and incognito mode.
Despite these steps, I still receive the same CORS error. Unfortunately, I do not have the ability to modify the client-side request.


What is strange is that I previously used the same google cloud storage bucket for another video, and there is no problem with that video (I can access it from my application, even though it has the same configuration (public access) as the problematic video).
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this?
I linked the 2 videos.
Thanks in advance for your help!
Problematic video : https://storage.googleapis.com/pomerleau/DJI_20240612165948_0001.MP4
Working access video : https://storage.googleapis.com/pomerleau/INSPECTION_C-EST_D-NORD_4min55.mp4
